# EJS array in JS function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

I have a `scores` array in my database.
I want to extract maximum value from that array in my ejs webpage.

I am not sure but tried the following code:

```
<div>
       <%-Math.max(user.scores)%>
</div>
```

This not giving the desired result.

For eg if the `scores` array is [1, 4, 99, 2, 7], it should give me 99 on my webpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javascript function Math.max() takes in a list of arguments and not a single argument aka an array.

Thus if you use the ES6 spread syntax for arrays it looks like this 
`Math.max(...user.scores)`

This will spread the elements of the array as arguments for the Math.max() function.

Here is the MDN documentation for the Math.max() function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: That's of great help. Thank you @phillip-schulze